ASUS H97-Plus and TPM 2.0
I bought for my ASUS H97-Plus motherboard this TPM 2.0 module, but it is not being recognized by the BIOS also after saving changes and restart,

Anyone can advise on how to make it work, if it's possible?

If the discrete TPM you purchased is not being detected, then your motherboard's firmware, does not support enabling TPM.  The discrete TPM was also unnecessary since your CPU has support for firmware based fTPM.

Thanks. In the motherboard's manual it is stated that TPM module is purchased separately, and no mention of fTPM.
Motherboard and CPU were purchased at the end on 2014 - if it helps.

I have the same problem. I bought a TPM 1.2 module and TPM 2.0 module for ASUS for the same motherboard. I updated the BIOS to the latest version. I could not make it work. Did you find a solution?

Unfortunately, no solution.
